# Missing scheme when generating path in twig

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 5.4.34 and Docker, I have a main domain and a sub-domain, each one have his own routes so in each controller I'm using this :

```php
/**
 * @Route("/", host="foo.bar", priority="1")
 */
final class FooController extends AbstractController
{
...
```

And

```php
/**
 * @Route("/", host="sub.foo.bar", priority="1")
 */
final class SubFooController extends AbstractController
{
...
```

This is my `services.yaml` extract :

```yaml
parameters:
    router.request_context.scheme: 'https'
    ...
```

Today path() generates URLs without scheme ! Am I missing something ?

Adding `schemes={"https"}` in the top annotation of each controller works locally, but not on prod server :(

Comment: By default, generated URLs use the same HTTP scheme as the current request. Try to force using HTTPS in your docker nginx container

Comment: how can I config it ? what should I add in nginx config file ?

Comment: yes you can add a 301 redirect  to https in the block listening to port 80;
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }